# Can one Android app have two different accountTypes?

Tags: android, android-account

As I know, an application can make its `accountType` by adding it in `XML` file like this:

```
android:accountType="com.android.app.test"
```

I want to know if **one** app can have **two** different `accountTypes` or **not**.

Answer (score 0):

For one [Authenticator](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-authenticator.html#CreateAuthenticatorFile), you can't have two different `accountType`, and also as per **docs** in your `Authenticator class`:

```
   // Don't add additional accounts
    @Override
    public Bundle addAccount(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
            String s,
            String s2,
            String[] strings,
            Bundle bundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }
```

you should not add **additional** accounts. So **yes** only one `accountType`. If you need another one create another `Authenticator`.